# Admin login script with PHP and MySQL username and password is incorrect despite of correct input

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in PHP and MySQL and I am making a login script for an admin but I can't seem to find the problem with the code below. The username and password is still incorrect even though it exists in the database and it was entered correctly in the form.

[image: Here is the screenshot of my "admin" table]

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['adminlogin-submit'])){

    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $username = $_POST['adminusername'];
    $password = $_POST['adminpassword'];

    if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
        header("Location: ../adminlogin.php?error=emptyfields");
        exit();
    }
    else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username=?;";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
            header("location: ../adminlogin.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        }
        else{
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $passwordCheck = password_verify($password, $row['password']);
                if($passwordCheck == false){
                    header("location: ../adminlogin.php?error=wrongpassword");
                    exit();
                }
                else if($passwordCheck == true){
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                    $_SESSION['adminusername'] = $row['username'];

                    header("location: ../adminlogin.php?login=success");
                    exit();
                }
                else{
                    header("location: ../adminlogin.php?error=unknownerror");
                    exit();
                }
            }
            else{
                header("location: ../adminlogin.php?error=nouser");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
else{
    header("location: ../adminlogin.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Storing passwords as plain text is never a good idea. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Yes thank you for the reminder. I was planning on hashing them later on but now I know that password_verify takes hash for the second parameter. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`password_verify` takes a *hash* of the password as second parameter, not the password itself.
in the table, the value within the password field should not be the plain password, but its hash.

check [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

To insert the correct hashed password into your table, use

```
$hashed_password = password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT );

$sql = "UPDATE admin SET password = ? WHERE username=?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) or die("SQL error");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $hashed_password, $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: I see. Initially, I used this same code for a customer login but the data came from a table where passwords are hashed. This answer has helped a lot. Thank you very much!

Comment: but the answer ist still **unsecure** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: i agree, this query should only be used to update the existing entries in the table.

Comment: Then change it please, every has to use prepared statements, to get used to it, independent for what purpose or for for what language

Comment: I can take my downvote away if you fix the SQL injection you have introduced.